# OWASP ZAP false positive on X-Frame-Options and non-existing html file

Tags: owasp, x-frame-options, zap

I am using OWASP ZAP to test my application for vulnerabilities.

I am using the quick start Attack with the URL of my login page.

I am running the application on Tomcat from Eclipse.

Currently there are 2 problems:

1. ZAP finds an html page that I deleted. It does not exist anywhere in my project and yet ZAP generates an alert on it. It did exist at the time of first run.
2. ZAP generates an alert about X-Frame-Content header although this header exists and can be seen in Firefox F12 Tools. I even wrote a simple simulator that attempts to IFrame my application login page and the browser blocks it.

I am guessing ZAP has some kind of cache and I did Exit and Delete Session but it did not change anything.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Kirill.

Answer (score 0):

ZAP stores everything in the session, so if you are starting with a new session then ZAP shouldnt be using anything from an old one.

Are these issues repeatable, eg with a new ZAP session?
If so click on the alerts and then look at the Response tab - it could be that your application is returning responses that you dont expect.

Comment: Yes, this is repeatable. I did Exit and Delete session, deleted the sites, alerts - everything I could find in the main screen. I also did New Session.

Comment: Can you provide any details? If not your going to have to investigate this yourself. You can start by looking at the responses related to the alerts and seeing if the app is returning something your not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

ZAP generates alerts for all the server responses 200 and 404. That is why I saw alert on the removed page - it was not found. This was also the reason for alerts on all the resources - they were found.
I configured my Tomcat to generate security headers and after that ZAP does not generate any alerts.

Answer (score 0):

This was covered in a User Group thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?pli=1#!topic/zaproxy-users/e764_WPWCRc

The URL clicked in the alert tree and displayed in the alert panel is the URL the alert applies to. Which is not necessarily the URL entered in the quick start tab.
The response an alert pertains to can be seen by selecting the alert and then going to the response tab (behind the quick start tab).

Once the user properly identified which urls/resour as were impacted they "... added security headers generation in Tomcat configuration and now there are no alerts."